# How realize SEF pagination (Ditto) - MODx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, modx, ditto

Is it possible realize SEF pagination on Ditto - MODx? How do it - in scripts / nginx configuration (or anyone know htaccess solution )

What means..
It's pages whith list of articles

/articles.php

/articles.php?start=10

....

So in result should be
/articles.php/start/10
or something like it

And realize correct redirect to SEF

I'm very grateful to you in advance.

Comment: http://forums.modx.com/thread/37914/seo-friendly-pagination-with-getpage

Comment: http://community.modx-cms.ru/blog/questions/2691.html

Comment: http://community.modx-cms.ru/blog/questions/1596.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use Ditto, you won't be able to do this without modifying the snippet code to set up paging as you require.

However, I would argue that /articles.php/start/10 is no more search friendly than the original as both 'start' and '10' are in no way related to the content on those pages. Google and the other search engines are certainly capable of distinguishing between pages with different url parameters in this case, however if this remains an issue you might be better off exploring a different way to create your listings.

Have a look here for some useful insights: 
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
http://www.seomoz.org/blog/pagination-best-practices-for-seo-user-experience